# Restrict User Team Name similar to Manager Team Name

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, validation-rule

I have created "Team Name" as multi-picklist on User object in Salesforce. I have requirement to restrict a user's "Team Name" field should have only 1 value and that value should match with his manager's "Team Name" field only for a specific role like 'Shift Manager' whenever new user gets created or existing one gets updated. For other roles anything is acceptable. I have done this using trigger and it is working fine. But I was asked to figure out if we can achieve this using Process Builder or Flow or using configurations only without using code.

Comment: This definitely sounds possible, did you try using the process builder? where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, but this condition should meet when we create or update user record and I did not find anything similar to before insert, before update context variable of trigger. Also I want to show error message but how we can achieve it in process builder or in flow.